# Headers in rows in using vuetify

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

I am using `vuetify 1.0.` I am using v-data-table component to display data. But the issue I am facing here is I am not able to figure out how can I display headers in row. Something like this as below.

```
Name:  XYZ
Location: PQR
Number: 000-000-0000
```

But right now the table looks something like this:

```
Name      Location    Number
XYZ
PQR
000-000-0000
```

In the code below, the manager_array consists of a single object.

```
<template>
  <v-card>
      <v-card>
        <v-container fluid>
          <v-data-table
            :headers="headers"
            :items="manager_array"
            hide-actions
            :disable-initial-sort="true">
            <template slot="items" slot-scope="props">
              <tr>{{ props.item.first_name }}</tr>
              <tr>{{ props.item.location }}</tr>
              <tr>{{ props.item.number }}</tr>
            </template>
          </v-data-table>
        </v-container>
      </v-card>
  </v-card>      
</template>

<script>

  export default {
    props: ['manager'],
    data () {
      return {
        manager_array: [],
        headers: [
          { text: 'Name', value: 'name'},
          { text: 'Location', value: 'location'},
          { text: 'Number', value: 'number'},
        ]
      }
    },
    created() {
      this.manager_array.push(this.manager)
    },
  };
</script>
```

Comment: May I ask first why you are using such an old version?

Comment: @AJT82 It's been a long time we have been using it. But yes we are planning to upgrade it.

Comment: Oh ok :) Hmm... looking at the documentation anywy I cannot see a way to do this out of the box though. Someone can correct me if I'm wrong .

Comment: But do you even need a table here? Seems you have just one `manager` in your table?

Comment: @AJT82 Yes, thats right. It is just one manager. Actually I wanted to match the data table layout styles in my app. So thats why I thought of using it v-data-table.

Comment: I think you are better off using a v-list or something else and just tweak the style a bit if needed, as it's only one data set.

Comment: If you only need the same style as that of the v-data-table then consider using v-simple-table.